# How To Identify Which Object is Nonetype and Which is str in Python and How do I Fix Concatenate Error?

Tags: python, string, installation, string-concatenation, nonetype

When trying to install pygames into my enthought canopy, I run the setup.py file and it always gives "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Nonetype' objects"

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Allie\Canopy\pygame-master\setup.py in <module>()
    145 # get compile info for all extensions
    146 try:
--> 147     extensions = read_setup_file('Setup')
    148 except:
    149     print ("""Error with the "Setup" file,

C:\Users\Allie\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.2.2785.win-x86\lib\distutils\extension.pyc in read_setup_file(filename)
    166 
    167             #print "original line: " + line
--> 168             line = expand_makefile_vars(line, vars)
    169             words = split_quoted(line)
    170             #print "expanded line: " + line

C:\Users\Allie\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.2.2785.win-x86\lib\distutils\sysconfig.pyc in expand_makefile_vars(s, vars)
    407         if m:
    408             (beg, end) = m.span()
--> 409             s = s[0:beg] + vars.get(m.group(1)) + s[end:]
    410         else:
    411             break

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Can anyone help me fix those lines to get my setup file running? Otherwise I don't know how to install pygames into canopy.

Answer (score 2):

The code tries to expand variables in your Makefile, but it could not find a specific variable.

The code first parses out all `VARNAME = value` entries, and then in a second step tries to insert values into `$(VARNAME)` and `${VARNAME}` references. It is that second step that failed as a variable name was not defined, or at least not *found* in the first step.

The `pygame` build system creates a makefile named `Setup` from a file named `Setup.in`, and it is the generated file that is failing here. Where `Setup.in` has a section marked with `#--StartConfig` / `#--EndConfig` variables should be written. You'll have to investigate what lines are missing and why.

You can rerun the `config.py` script to re-generate the file; it delegates to platform-specific modules for the work.

Answer (score 0):

@ageoca, since you've asked how to identify the None Type, you might want to try a simple if statement:

```
if v != None:
    print(len(v))
else:
    print(-1)
```

Using this, you could develop a strategy for this exception you're facing.

You can also find a nice little tutorial describing this in a little bit more detail on dotnetpearls.com -> http://www.dotnetperls.com/none-python